# Logic to randomly reorder remaining tile positions using a tile map array

Tags: algorithm, grid, permutation, tiles

The title explains most of the question.
I have a tile grid which is represented by a 2D array. Some tiles are marked as empty (but they exist in the array, for certain continued uses) while others are in normal state.

What I need to do is, to reorder the remaining (non-empty) tiles in the grid so that all (or most) are in a different *non-empty* position. If I just iterate all the non-empty positions and swap the tile with another random one, I might be already reordering many of them automatically (the swapped ones).

So I was wondering if there's some technique I can follow so as to reorder the grid satisfactorily with minimal looping. Any hints?

Comment: How randomly do the tiles need to be swapped?  If randomness is not important, you could just cycle the tiles one step forward by replacing 1 with 2, 2 with 3, ..., and N with 1.  If randomness is important, then you are trying to find a **derangement** of the original tiles and want to generate one randomly.

Comment: Yes, a **derangement** is what I want! I was wondering if I could do it in-place rather than saving the non-empty tiles and distributing them randomly. Then again, I can use only the non-empty positions, so picking a random spot from the map _and_ checking if it's empty might make up a lot of unproductive checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
public void RandomizeGrid<T>(T[,] grid, Func<T,bool> isEmpty)
{
    // Create a list of the indices of all non-empty cells.  
    var indices = new List<Point>();
    int width = grid.GetLength(0);
    int height = grid.GetLength(1);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if (!isEmpty(grid[x,y])) // function to check emptiness
            {
                indices.Add(new Point(x,y));
            }
        }
    }

    // Randomize the cells using the index-array as displacement.
    int n = indices.Count;
    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j = rnd.Next(i,n); // Random index i <= j < n
        if (i != j)
        {
            // Swap the two cells
            var p1 = indices[i];
            var p2 = indices[j];
            var tmp = grid[p1.X,p1.Y];
            grid[p1.X,p1.Y] = grid[p2.X,p2.Y];
            grid[p2.X,p2.Y] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it meet your needs ("satisfactorily" is a bit vague) to ensure that every non empty tile was swapped with one other non-empty tile one time?

Say you have a list :

```
(1,4,7,3,8,10)
```

we can write down the indicies of the list

```
(0,1,2,3,4,5)
```

and perform N random swaps on the indices to shuffle it - maybe some numbers move, some don't.

```
(5,1,3,2,4,0)
```

Then take these pairwise as a sequence of swaps to perform on our original list.

```
(8,10,3,7,1,4)
```

if you have an odd number of elements, the leftover is swapped with any other element in the list.

Comment: I am working on a 2D array. Any thoughts as to how to randomize 2D indices (which are non-empty) ?

Comment: The fact that they are in a 2d array is beside the point. They are just things that have places.